# Webcrawl with R

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, web-crawler

I have a problem I would like some help at. I need to create a piece of R code that can load in a csv file. The csv file contain one column named "Link" and for each i(Row) there is a link from which the code need to download the content of the link and place it in a separate csv file. Until now I have managed find and modify the piece of code showed below. (Thanks to Christopher Gandrud and co authors)

```
library(foreign)
library(RCurl)

addresses <- read.csv(">>PATH TO CSV FILE<<")

for (i in addresses) full.text <- getURL(i)

text <- data.frame(full.text)

outpath <-">>PATH TO SPECIFIED FOLDER<<"

x <- 1:nrow(text)

for(i in x) {
  write(as.character(text[i,1]), file = paste(outpath,"/",i,".txt",sep=""))
}
```

Actually the code works perfectly, BUT the problem is that I am overloading the server with requests, so after having downloaded the correct content from 100-150 links, the files are just empty. I know for a fact that this is the problem since I have tested it many times with a decreasing number of links. Actually if I just download 100 links at the time it is no problem. Above 100 it starts becoming a problem. Non the less I need to implement a couple of things into this piece of code for it to become a good crawler for this particular task.

I have divided my problem into two because solving problem one should solve the case temporarily.

1. I want to use the Sys.Sleep function for every 100 downloads. So the code fires 100 requests for the first 100 links and then it pauses for x seconds before it fires the next 100 requests...
2. Having done that with all rows/links in my dataset/csv file I need it to check each csv file for two conditions. They cannot be empty and they cannot contain a certain error message the server gives me in some special cases. If one of these two condtions are true then it need to save the filename(link number) into a vector I can work with from there.

Wow this question suddenly got pretty long. I realize it is a big question and I am asking a lot. It is for my master thesis which is not really about R programming but I need to download the content from a lot of websites which I have been given access to. Next I have to analyze the content, which is what my thesis is about. Any suggestions/comments are welcome.

---

```
 library(foreign)  
 library(RCurl)  

 addresses <- read.csv("~/Dropbox/Speciale/Mining/Input/Extract post - Dear Lego n(250).csv")  

 for (i in addresses) {  
+   if(i == 50) {  
+     print("Why wont this work?")  
+     Sys.sleep(10)  
+     print(i)  
+   }  
+   else {  
+     print(i)  
+   }  
+ }
```

"And then a whole list over the links loaded in. No "Why wont this work" at i == 50" followed by

Warning message

```
In if (i == 100) {:
 the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used  
full.text <- getURL(i)  
text <- data.frame(full.text)  
outpath <-"~/Dropbox/Speciale/Mining/Output"  
x <- 1:nrow(text)  
for(i in x) {  
write(as.character(text[i,1]), file = paste(outpath,"/",i,".txt",sep=""))}
```

Able to help me more?

Comment: i recommend breaking this into two questions. As to your first, why don't you just put a conditional to check if your iterator is a multiple of 100, i.e. `if i%%100 == 0 then Sys.sleep(yourTimeHere)`...

Comment: I agree with regards to the two questions (Im new, and will try to adjust). Can see someone proposed to change my question.

I will try to solve the thing you proposed and i will post the solution as soon as i have it.

My basic problem is that have basic skills of VBA programming but just started with R. SO i do not know exactly how the different loops work and how to make a "Counter" for i, as i would have done easily in VBA.

Comment: The basic construct is more or less the same, though i will auto-increment in R...to test this, do `for (i in 1:10) {print(i)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINAL SOLUTION:

```
> library(RCurl)  
> library(foreach)  
> library(foreign)

> z <- nrow(links)  
> outpath <-"SPECIFIC PATH"

> foreach(i=1:z) %do% {    
+  text <- getURL(links[i,])    
+  write(as.character(text), file = paste(outpath,"/",i,".txt",sep=""))}
```

Comment: Just to wrap up this thread of how to build a scraber / crawler that can download a vector of specified URL's and save each and one of them into specific text files.

I ended up not needing the Sys.sleep function as this function is "slow enough". However this gives me a problem as it is actually a bit to slow, but it is able to solve my problem with a bit of manual work.

Special thanks to Chase, as he helped me along the way. I realize that the final solution was not near Chase's but i learned a lot from his posts.

Kasper

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on my comments - here's a basic concept to put in a Sys.sleep half way through your loop.

```
for (i in 1:10) { 
  if(i == 5) {
      print("halfwayhome")
      Sys.sleep(5)
      print(i)
  }
  else { 
      print(i)
  }
}
```

Results in:

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] "halfwayhome"
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10
```

So I don't have any experience with RCurl or parsing HTML pages, so I conveniently avoided that part of your task. However, I was able to successfully generate a list of addresses, download them with `readLines()` and then write them back out. I put a `Sys.sleep()` call after each one, and things seem to work peachy.

```
links <- c("http://news.lugnet.com/dear-lego/?n=1",
           "http://news.lugnet.com/dear-lego/?n=2",
           "http://news.lugnet.com/dear-lego/?n=3",
           "http://news.lugnet.com/dear-lego/?n=4",
           "http://news.lugnet.com/dear-lego/?n=5",
           "http://news.lugnet.com/dear-lego/?n=6",
           "http://news.lugnet.com/dear-lego/?n=7",
           "http://news.lugnet.com/dear-lego/?n=8",
           "http://news.lugnet.com/dear-lego/?n=9",
           "http://news.lugnet.com/dear-lego/?n=10"
           )

for (j in 1:length(links)){
  dat <- readLines(links[j])
  write.table(dat, paste0("outfile",j,"txt"))
  Sys.sleep(5)
  cat("Finished file", j)
}
```

I'd ask a new/different question if you need to parse those HTML pages or get something more useful out of them, I probably won't be of much assistance on that front.

Hope this helps,
-Chase

Comment: Arh yes, just the help i needed. I will have to jump to bed now but i will work on the code tomorrow. Thanks a lot for the help. It is really appreciated. (Took my like 20 hours to get from "There must be some software that can do this for me" to "Hmm looks like I will have to code it myself, which i also fun)

Comment: @KasperChristensen - if this answer "answers" your question, there is a blank "checkmark" next to it that you can click on to signify that. The "Up" and "Down" arrows can also be used to signify "this answer is useful" or not. Both of those actions result in "reputation" for the person answering...which is the "currency of Stack Overflow". The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) explains this much better than I do, so I'd check it out. Good luck!

Comment: Seems like i have to get into this forum as it is a bit more organized than i thought, which is nice. Thanks a lot until now. I will try to make the code work tonight and will definately give you some reputation points.

Comment: Seems like i still need your help. I wrote this code but it still does not give me the data is was looking for... Seems like that "Sys.sleep" is at the wrong place as it still seems to fire all requests at once?

Comment: Hmm that sounds strange. Nice if you could have a look at it. This link should take you to the folder i have created with a couple of csv files. dropbox.com/sh/fmop29u2s17n45p/Y3bH5R8KMy

Comment: @KasperChristensen - updated my answer, hope this is closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: Can people who down voted this question please let me know what their critique is as the question has been answered?